# How can I prevent images produced by "Save for web and device" being cropped to their content?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

My artboard size is 48 x 48, but when I "Save for web and device", the created png file is auto cropped to the size of the art inside (40 x 50 in my case), just like the "export" option. Could you please help me find a way to fix it?

Comment: It suddenly went wrong just 2 hours ago:((.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Save for Web dialog window check the "Clip to Artboard" option if you want the Save for Web image size to match the artboard size.

It's always a good idea to post what **version** of any app you are using as well as the operating system.

Comment: Thank for your help. I'll remember your advice at the next question:D.